# Can chain rule for derivatives be extended to partial derivatives?

Tags: partial-derivative

I know that this is true for all cases, via chain rule:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{du}\frac{du}{dv}\frac{dv}{dx}$$

However, is this allowed?

$$(\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{x}})_z=(\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{u}})_z(\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{v}})_z(\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{x}})_z$$

Assuming the variable that is held constant is z(that does not appear anywhere within the partial derivatives).

Comment: Notation is strange, but in any case the answer is no. [Multivariable chain rule](https://www.math.hmc.edu/calculus/tutorials/multichainrule/) is a bit more complicated.